# SwiftUI - Can't Scroll with Drag Gesture in List

Tags: list, swiftui, scrollview, gesture

I've run into a similar problem, when using a DragGesture with a List in a ScrollView, as I've seen in other questions, but none of the solutions presented have worked for my situation.

I've tried the

```
onTapGesture {}
```

before the DragGesture solution and nothing changed.

I've also tried the

```
delaysTouches(for: 0.1) {}
```

solution mentioned here:
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/forums/swiftui/a-guide-to-delaying-gestures-in-scrollview/6005 but still nothing changed.

I am implementing an overlay when a user taps a selection in order to provide better visual feedback over Apple's native "slightly dim the tapped selection" implementation, but the user must still be able to scroll.

Here's some code:

```
struct TestView: View {

    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @State private var tappedNumber: Int?

    var body: some View {

        ZStack {
            Color.blue
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            VStack {
                VStack(spacing: 10) {
                    List {
                        Section {
                            ForEach(1...150, id: \.self) { number in
                                HStack {
                                    Text("\(number)")
                                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                                }
                                .padding()
                                .background(Color.red)
                                .contentShape(Rectangle())
                                .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                                .simultaneousGesture(
                                    DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                                        .onChanged({ _ in
                                            tappedNumber = number
                                        })
                                        .onEnded({ _ in
                                            tappedNumber = nil
                                            dismiss()
                                    })
                                )
                                .overlay(
                                    tappedNumber == number ?
                                        Color.primary.opacity(0.4)
                                    :
                                        nil
                                )
                            }
                        }
                        .listRowInsets(
                            EdgeInsets(
                                top: 0,
                                leading: 0,
                                bottom: 0,
                                trailing: 0
                            )
                        )
                        .listRowSeparator(.visible)
                        .listSectionSeparator(.hidden)
                    }
                    .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
                    
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need the user to be able to scroll as they normally would, but when they tap a selection, the overlay should show, to provide the intended visual feedback. If I can avoid a delay in the user experience that would be the preferred solution.